# How to get the input using the edit text continuously when the button is clicked removing the previous value in edit text

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get the value from the user using edit text continuously. When they clicked the button then for the first time I am getting the value but when I want to tab in edit text to get the second value, the first value is already there which I want to get cleared and get the new value. But it is not working.

I tried using edittext.getText().clear(); and edittext.setText(" "). It will be cleared but when I enter the value and clicked the button, it not returning any value. It returning Null.

```
val = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.v);
check = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Check);
String value1;

 check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            value1 = val.getText().toString();
            enterValue.setText(value1);

            if(!value1.isEmpty()) {
                try {
                    value = Integer.parseInt(value1);
                    //Checking the user input value:

                    if (value > max) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Guess the Value Lower than " + String.valueOf(max), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else if(value < min) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Guess the Value greater than " + String.valueOf(min), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

 .
 .
 .
```

What I expected is that when the check button is clicked then I will be getting the value and the edittext val is cleared such that for the next time, when I clicked a button it will return the new value that is been entered.

Comment: `value1 = val.getText().toString();` Are you sure this line is working for you without any error?. Because you have already declared `value1` as `int` and assigning string value with it.

Comment: `enterValue.setText(value1);` and this line also. EditText never accepts Integer values. So better set integer in EditText like this > `enterValue.setText(""+value1);`

Answer (score 0):

You should have posted further code.It's really hard to guess where your problem lies.
Anyway,declare your `value1` variable as String not int and then try your method. If it still does not work,

Try this method :

```
public void checkValue(View view){
     value1 = val.getText().toString();
     enterValue.setText(value1);

           if(!value1.equals("")) {
                try {
                    value = Integer.parseInt(value1);
                    //Checking the user input value:

                    if (value > max) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Guess the Value Lower than " + String.valueOf(max), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else if(value < min) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Guess the Value greater than " + String.valueOf(min), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

 .
 .
 . //Put here whatever your further code is.

     edittext.setText("");

}
```

go to your xml file and set the `onClick` attribute of your button as the above method `checkValue` .

Answer (score 0):

```
Edittext val;

inside button.setOnClickListener(){

      val.settext(null);
}
```

this worked for me. Thank you for your time and response.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the problem near value1? You try set String into int.